# Indexer with multiple return types

Tags: c#

I'm using Indexers in my class to make searching through a list easier. However, I want to be able to return both a bool and an int. Not at the same time but determine whether it's a bool or an int and then return it.

```
public class uPermissions
{

    private List<uPermission> permissions = new List<uPermission> ()
    {
        new uPermission ("canBuild", false),
        new uPermission ("canClaim", false),
        new uPermission ("canUnClaim", false),
        new uPermission ("canInvite", false),
        new uPermission ("canKick", false),
        new uPermission ("canSetHome", false)
    };
    private List<uConstraint> constraints = new List<uConstraint> ();

    public bool this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            return permissions.Where (p => p.name == index).First ().allowed;
        }
        set
        {
            permissions.Where (p => p.name == index).First ().allowed = value;
        }
    }
    public int this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            return constraints.Where (c => c.name == index).First ().count;
        }
        set
        {
            constraints.Where (c => c.name == index).First ().count = value;
        }
    }

    public bool exists (string permission)
    {
        var perm = permissions.Where (p => p.name.ToLower () == permission.ToLower ()).First ();
        return (perm != null) ? true : false;
    }

    public void setAllTrue ()
    {
        foreach (uPermission p in permissions)
        {
            p.allowed = true;
        }
    }
    public void setAllFalse ()
    {
        foreach (uPermission p in permissions)
        {
            p.allowed = false;
        }
    }
}

public class uConstraint
{
    public string name;
    public int count;

    public uConstraint () { }
    public uConstraint (string name, int count)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    } 
}

public class uPermission
{
    public string name;
    public bool allowed;

    public uPermission () { }
    public uPermission (string name, bool allowed)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.allowed = allowed;
    }
}
```

That's my code. I saw something about templates while searching but I don't understand how it works or if it's even the right solution. If anyone can give some insight it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: perhaps you should considera dictionary - it would be faster.

Comment: I would use a dictionary but this is a extension onto another software and it uses xml to store data but the xml parse doesnt parse dictionaries

Comment: So how would you distinguish when you should return bool and when int? You pass the same string argument in both cases.

Comment: How does the caller of this method declare the variable into which they assign the result of calling this method that might return an `int` or might return a `bool`. If they already have to know what the correct type is in order to declare that variable, what's the supposed advantage here?

Comment: Why not use method `GetAllowed` and `GetCount` instead of indexer?

Comment: I'd suggest an `enum` with a `[Flags]` attribute for the Permissions instead of the current design.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? This is a bad design - you (ab)use an indexer to perform something that has nothing to do with indexing

Comment: If your intention is to store privileges and permissions, it would be a *lot* better to *separate* privileges and permissions. `canBuild` is a privilege. That looks like a class. Someone can have a `Grant` or `Deny` permission on it. That looks like *two* different lists. Can he have *both*? Or only one at a time? You'll have to create `Grant* and `Deny` methods that implement that logic, taking care to clean up duplicates. Which takes precedence? Grant or Deny? You'll have to implement *that* logic in an `IsAllowed` method

Answer (score 1):

C# will not allow you to distinguish overloads purely based on their return types (they must differ in at least one parameter type or type argument count).
You can create a generic method and use the type argument to distinguish between your two intentions. E.g.

```
class uPermissions {
   public T GetAllowedOrCount<T>(string index) {
     get {
       if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool) {
         return permissions.Where (p => p.name == index).First ().allowed;
       } else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int) {
         return constraints.Where (c => c.name == index).First ().count;
       }
       throw new InvalidOperationException("only bool and int are supported");
     }
}
```

and then you'd call it with an explicit type argument, such as

```
var fooCount = uPermissions.GetAllowedOrCount<int>("foo")
var fooAllowed = uPermissions.GetAllowedOrCount<string>("foo")
```

Note that this solution would not work with the `this` indexer as C# does not support generic indexers.

I suppose though we agree that this does not sound like something you'd want to do. Your dispatch is now run-time as opposed to compile-time and you would certainly not gain type safety as

```
uPermissions.GetAllowedOrCount<double>("foo")
```

would also compile and blow up with a runtime exception.

To be honest I also would find it very confusing that the same (or overloaded) method returns/sets two totally different things (i.e. allowed vs count). I'd rather have two different methods for that or return a data structure (that has a getter for allowed/count) from a single method. In the latter case you could also use indexers if that is what you fancy.

Comment: Just to add the right nomenclature: C# requires unique **signatures** from each method. A signature is comprised of the method's name and its parameter types (in that specific order and amount). The return type of a method is not part of the signature. This same principle applies to indexing, where the only significant part of the signature is the type of the index parameter as there is no name.

Comment: chaining `if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)` kinds of checks is an OCP violation. That's a different discussion, but relevant to point out that the solution provided here is not optimal, though it does solve the specific issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The overload resolution mechanism in C# doesn't regard return values. You can't have two methods with the same name and argument, differing only in their return type.

Indexer is just a method (or two), so it follows the same rules. You can't have two indexers with the same arguments, differing only in their return type.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use two different properties each containing a dictionary or some List-type instead. That way you could write something like this:

```
bool foo = uPermissionsInstance.Permissions["someName"];
int bar = uPermissionsInstance.Constraints["someOtherName"];
```

Alternatively there's a "hack" you could use, that works quite well:

- Write a Class that has two implicit casts implemented. One for int and one for bool.
- Return this class instead of the int or bool and set its internal value appropriately.

That way you can write the following. But this won't work with the setter!

```
bool foo = uPermissionsInstance["someName"];
int bar = uPermissionsInstance["someOtherName"];
```

Implementation:

```
public IntBoolValue this[string index]
{
    get
    {
        // Here you need to check whether you can find an entry in permissions or in constraints. Then return the found value.
        return new IntBoolValue(permissions.Where (p => p.name == index).First ().allowed);
    }
}

// ------------------

internal struct IntBoolValue
{
    internal int internalInt;
    internal bool internalBool;

    public IntBoolValue(int value) { this.internalInt = value; }
    public IntBoolValue(bool value) { this.internalBool = value; }

    public static implicit operator bool(IntBoolValue value)
    {
        return value.internalBool;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(IntBoolValue value)
    {
        return value.internalInt;
    }
}
```